Command to purge and msgsel date format
I'm trying this to periodically purge messages that are older than 3 days.
When I run this command line:
activemq purge --msgsel "JMSTimestamp < $(date -d '-3 days' +%s000)" MYQUEUE

or
activemq purge --msgsel "JMSTimestamp < '$(date -d '-3 days' +%s000)'" MYQUEUE

I get this error:
INFO: Loading '/opt/apache-activemq-5.16.4//bin/env'
INFO: Using java '/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'
;: 1: ;: cannot open 1731681609000: No such file

I also tried:
activemq purge --msgsel "JMSTimestamp < 1731939258969" MYQUEUE

where 1731939258969 is the timestamp of an existing message in MYQUEUE, and faced the same issue.
However, for instance, --mgsel "JMSPriority=0" works fine.
What is the syntax for date and JMSTimestamp?

We use Debian.
I also tried to replace the "date" syntax with the timestamp value of an existing message in the queue "JMSTimestamp < 1731939258969" and faced the same issue.

yes, sorry : we use bash

Please add details about how you used JMSTimestamp < 1731939258969 to the question itself. That's an important detail that shouldn't be relegated to the comments.

ok, I have added it

When you specified JMSTimestamp < 1731939258969 you still got an error containing cannot open 1731681609000: No such file? Using activemq purge --msgsel "JMSTimestamp < 1731939258969" MYQUEUE works fine when I try it. There are no errors.

Yes, I get the same error.
";: 1: ;: cannot open 1731939258969: No such file"

After many tests I found that
--mgsel "'JMSTimestamp < $(date -d '-3 days' +%s000)'"

works on my box. According to the help I should not have to add single quotes to double ones, but it works.
